# Find the possible values of $a$ and $b$

Tags: functions

Here is a question from an IB past paper -

> The function $f$ is such that $f(x)=a^{2}x^{2}-ax+3b\;$ for
>   $\;\displaystyle x\leq\frac{1}{2a},\;$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.
>
> For the case where $f(-2)=4a^{2}-b+8\;$ and $f(-3)=7a^{2}-b+14,\;$
>   find the possible values of $a$ and $b$.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

My working so far -

Since $\displaystyle x\leq\frac{1}{2a},$

$\Rightarrow\;\displaystyle -2\leq\frac{1}{2a}$

$\therefore\;\displaystyle a\leq-\frac{1}{4}$

$\Rightarrow\;\displaystyle -3\leq\frac{1}{2a}$

$\therefore\;\displaystyle a\leq-\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting into the equation of $f$, we get that $f(-2) = 4a^2+2a+3b.$ Equating this with the given value gives $f(-2) = 4a^2+2a+3b = 4a^2-b+8\Rightarrow b=2-\dfrac{a}{2}.$ Now substituting $-3$ for $x$ in the equation of $f$ gives $9a^2+3a+3b$. This expression is equal to $7a^2-b+14$. Equating these two expressions gives $2a^2+3a+4b-14=0$. Now subbing $b=2-\dfrac{a}{2}$ into this expression yields $2a^2+a-6=0\Rightarrow (2a-3)(a+2) = 0\Rightarrow a=\dfrac{3}{2}, -2$. The corresponding values of $b$ are $\dfrac{5}{4}$ and $3$, so the possible answers $(a,b)$ are $(\dfrac{3}{2},\dfrac{5}{4})$ and $(-2,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $x=-2$ and $x=-3$ into $f(x)$ and equate with the expressions you're given to set up some simultaneous equations involving $a$ and $b$.